# How to check if a string ends with another (EndsWith) in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I need to write a logic in some Inno Setup function that checks if a string ends with another.

Can I use `StrUtils` Pascal functions (`EndsWith`) to do so?

```pascal
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  dir_value: String; app_name: String; 
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then
    begin
      dir_value := "C:\work\ABC"
      app_name :=  "ABC"

      { I need to write a logic here to check if dir_value ends with app_name }
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `EndsWith` in Inno Setup.

But you can easily implement it:

```pascal
function EndsWith(SubText, Text: string): Boolean;
var
  EndStr: string;
begin
  EndStr := Copy(Text, Length(Text) - Length(SubText) + 1, Length(SubText));
  // Use SameStr, if you need a case-sensitive comparison
  Result := SameText(SubText, EndStr);
end;
```

---

Though in your case, you actually need something like this:

```pascal
function EndsWithFileName(FileName, Path: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := SameText(FileName, ExtractFileName(Path));
end;
```

---

*For [`SameText`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_sametext) (and [`SameStr`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_samestr)), you need Inno Setup 6. On older versions, you can replace them with [`CompareText`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_comparetext) (and [`CompareStr`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_comparestr)).*

Comment: EndsWithFileName is much better than EndsWith based approach.
Thanks again bro!